# Basic Biomedical Text Mining in R

Tags: r, nlp, bioinformatics

I was trying to do some basic text mining on PubMed abstracts. I am getting the following error while inspecting my document-term matrix.

```
Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(dtm, 1:5, 1:20) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Code:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
dtm
inspect(dtm[1:5, 1:20])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell, since you don't provide a reproducible example, but I'd guess that the dimensions of `dtm` are smaller than `[5, 20]`. The example below shows a similar error message because of this reason.

```r
# Load package
library(tm)
#> Loading required package: NLP

# Load data
data("crude")

# Create dtm
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude)

# Examine dimensions
dim(dtm)
#> [1]   20 1266

# Inspect dtm - no problems
inspect(dtm[1:5, 1:5])
#> <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 5, terms: 5)>>
#> Non-/sparse entries: 1/24
#> Sparsity           : 96%
#> Maximal term length: 10
#> Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
#> Sample             :
#>      Terms
#> Docs  ... "(it) "demand "expansion "for
#>   127   0     0       0          0    0
#>   144   0     0       1          0    0
#>   191   0     0       0          0    0
#>   194   0     0       0          0    0
#>   211   0     0       0          0    0

# Inspect outside of dimensions of dtm
inspect(dtm[1:21, 1:5])
#> Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(dtm, 1:21, 1:5): subscript out of bounds
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I checked the dimension of my document matrix. It contains 4 documents and 3726 terms. I modified the command to inspect(dtm[1:4, 1:20]. Still getting following error: dim(dtm)
[1]    4 3726
> #inspect dtm
> inspect(dtm[1:4, 1:20])          <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 4, terms: 20)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 36/44
Sparsity           : 55%
Maximal term length: 189
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(x, docs, terms) : 
  Repeated indices currently not allowed.

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So, in your question you need to include data + code so that we can reproduce the problem ourselves by copy and pasting, otherwise we're just guessing.